# Visual Studio Appears to be ignoring my IF function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've been trying to practice small parts of my coding for an impending assignment but for the life of me I can't get visual studio to recognise that there's an `if` function, it just completely skips over it. The window closes as soon as I press enter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cout << "Enter first number.";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter second number.";
    cin >> b;
    if( a > b)

    {
        cout << "Variable a is greater than variable b." << endl;
        cout << "Value of a is " << a << " value of b is " << b << endl;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Try printing a and b regardless, see what the values actually are. Something might be happening in your input that causes unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I can lay your fears to rest: your `IF` statement is perfectly fine. The window simply closes when the program finishes executing. Since the program finishes executing immediately after the `IF` statement finishes executing, that's all she wrote.

Comment: Try launching with Ctrl+F5

Answer (score 0):

Not portable but, as you're using Visual Studio, you're on Windows, so it'll work. When you works in Debug mode, with Visual Studio, you don't need to add system("pause"), or something else, to your program. So I guess you're working in Release mode.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cout << "Enter first number.";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter second number.";
    cin >> b;
    if( a > b)

    {
        cout << "Variable a is greater than variable b." << endl;
        cout << "Value of a is " << a << " value of b is " << b << endl;

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

EDIT :
You shouldn't use [std::endl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) for a new line, or at least not each time you need a new line. You should just write `<< "\n";` `std::endl` insert a new line character + flushes the buffer. That's important to understand the difference between `<< std::endl;` and `<< "\n";`